# Get value from custom column from customer_entity

Tags: magento2, database, customer, magento-2.1

I'm having an issue with getting data from custom column I added in `customer_entity`. I added a column `typo3_password` in UpdateSchema.php and now I need to get data from this column. Trying to do that using `getTypo3Password()` method and adding CustomerInterface in module's Api\Data but it doesn't work.

```
 $customer       = $this->customerRepository->get($username);
 $customerId     = $customer->getId();
 $typoHashFromDb = $customer->getTypo3Password();
```

Any ideas? Do I need to add my custom Customer Model as well?

-- edit

Adding the custom CustomerInterface I created.

```
 const TYPO3_PASSWORD = 'typo3_password';

/**
 * Get Typo3 Password
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getTypo3Password();

/**
 * @param string $typo3password
 * @return $this
 */
public function setTypo3Password($typo3password);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customer entity is an EAV entity, and a customer's properties are organized with attributes in the table `eav_attribute`.

After you added a customer attribute, you don't have to create a getter or a setter. Magic methods will take care of it, and `getTypo3Password()` will automatically be available.

You can also use `getData('typo3_password')`.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't really work. I'm not adding an attribute in `eav_attribute`, but instead I'm adding a column in `customer_entity` table in database and want to get the data out of this column. Any ideas with this?

Comment: This is the completely wrong approach. You should use an attribute, Magento EAV entities work this way. I don't know how it could work with a column; and I don't know why anyone should want this. ;)